# Changing the measure of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I am trying to understand how to change the measure of a stochastic process using Girsanov's theorem.

In particular, I have the process $dX_t = a dt + dB_t$ for $t \in [0,T]$, and some arbitrary, well-behaved function $v(X)$, where $X$ denotes the path of $X_t$ up to $T$.

I have the quantity $\mathbb{E}_\tilde{a}[v(X)]$, where the subscript $\tilde{a}$ denotes that the expectation is taken with respect to the measure associated with $dX_t = \tilde{a} + dB_t$. (Hopefully this statement does make sense.)

Now I would like to differentiate this quantity with respect to $\tilde{a}$, and evaluate it at $\tilde{a} = a$.

My **first interpretation** of Girsanov's theorem is that I can write

$\mathbb{E}_\tilde{a}[v(X)] = \mathbb{E}_0[v(X)e^{\tilde{a}B_T-\frac{1}{2}\tilde{a}^{2}T}]=\mathbb{E}_a[v(X)e^{(\tilde{a}-a)B_T-\frac{1}{2}(\tilde{a}^{2}-a^2)T}]$

Differentiating this with respect to $\tilde{a}$ and evaluating the derivative at $\tilde{a}=a$ gives

$\frac{d}{da}\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{a}}\left[v(X)\right]=\mathbb{E}_{a}\left[v\left(B_{T}-aT\right)\right]$

My **second interpretation** of Girsanov's theorem is that I can write

$\mathbb{E}_\tilde{a}[v(X)] = \mathbb{E}_a[v(X)e^{(\tilde{a}-a)B_T-\frac{1}{2}(\tilde{a}-a)^2T}]$

in which case I get

$\frac{d}{da}\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{a}}[v(X)]=\mathbb{E}_{a}[vB_{T})]$

Clearly, only one (or possibly) none of these are correct, and I would like to understand which one, and why. Thank you! :)

Comment: Why is Girsanov involved at all? It seems you are considering $$g(a)=E(\nu(X^a_t))$$ where $dX^a_t=dB_t+adt$ and (presumably) $X^a_0=0$, hence $X^a_t=B_t+at$ and $$g(a)=E(\nu(B_t+at))$$ which yields $$g(a)=\int_\mathbb R \nu(x)\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-(x-at)^2/2t}dx$$ Thus, $$g'(a)=\int_\mathbb R \nu(x)\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}(x-at)e^{-(x-at)^2/2t}dx$$ that is, $$g'(a)=E(B_t\nu(B_t+at))=E((X^a_t-at)\nu(X^a_t))$$

Comment: Thank you @Did! The function $v(\cdot)$ depends not only on $X^a_t$, but on the entire path of the process up to time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - figured out the answer. The first interpretation is incorrect, while the second interpretation is correct. 
When I change the measure in two steps (as in the first interpretation), in the second change of measure, the Brownian motion $B_T$ is with respect to the measure $P^0$, not $P^{\tilde{a}}$. Once I write it properly, the two-step approach gives the same answer as the one-step approach, as it should.